# How do I pass the request object to the method_decorator in django class views?

Tags: python, django

I have been working on this all day.

I am trying to write custom permission for class views to check if user is in a certain group of permissions.

```
def rights_needed(reguest):
  if request.user.groups.filter(Q(name='Admin')).exists():
    pass
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/log-in/')

@method_decorator(rights_needed, name='dispatch')
class AdminView(CreateView):
    model = Admin
    form_class = AdminForm
    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'clinic/visitform_list.html'
```

Could help me know how I can achieve this? Or an easier way around it?

I also tried this (code inside AdminView class):

```
    def dispatch(self, request):
        if request.user.groups.filter(Q(name='Admin')).exists():
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/log-in/')
```

Comment: That second snippet should work, although it needs to accept `*args, **kwargs`. What happens when you try?

Comment: *args not defined so I changed `def dispatch(self, request)` to `def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs).`

Comment: this gave the error `dispatch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: so i fixed it with `return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks man. I wouldn't have seen the error until you said it should work. I had already abandoned the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator is a function that takes a function (a view in this case), and returns another function (a view in this case). At the moment your `rights_needed` looks like a regular view - it’s returning a response not a function.

Django comes with a `user_passes_test` method that makes it easy to create decorators like this. Since you are using class based views, it would be even easier to use the [`UserPassesTest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) mixin.

Your test function for the mixin would be:

```
def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.groups.filter(Q(name='Admin')).exists()
```

Comment: Potent. I fixed the error but your answer is sleek.